# SSH "connection refused" diagnostics?

Tags: ssh

I'm getting a constant "connection refused" while trying to connect over SSH from OS X to a CentOS VPS with a WHM control panel. SSH is enabled in WHM, and I've generated SSH keys. I also tried SSH with the firewall off for a minute , but no luck.

After perusing other questions, I've run `ssh -vv root@xx.xxx.xx.xx` and that gives me:

```
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: connect to address xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22: Connection refused
```

and running  `nc -zvw 2 xx.xxx.xx.xx 22` gives me

```
nc: connect to xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22 (tcp) failed: Connection refused
```

What do these really mean? What else can I try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The port appears to be closed (or filtered, but you say you've already tried disabling the firewall - you mean the one on the VPS, right?).

Can you please post the output of this command on the VPS if you have access by other means?

```
netstat -ntlp
```

It should list all open ports. Check port 22 is up on the right IP if you have several.

Do you have outgoing traffic firewall rules on the OSX client?

Edit: I took the liberty of running a port scan against that host and it doesn't seem to have a firewall up anyway, as many ports are open (you should probably close some or most when you can). SSH doesn't seem to be up though:

```
Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-04-13 15:36 GMT+3
Interesting ports on ns1.resume-resource.com (72.249.28.26):
Not shown: 958 filtered ports, 31 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
25/tcp   open  smtp
53/tcp   open  domain
80/tcp   open  http
110/tcp  open  pop3
143/tcp  open  imap
443/tcp  open  https
465/tcp  open  smtps
993/tcp  open  imaps
995/tcp  open  pop3s
2200/tcp open  unknown
```

Try `/etc/init.d/sshd restart` and check `/var/log/messages` for errors.

Comment: Actually, it looks like sshd is running on port 2200.  ssh -p 2200 72.249.28.26

Comment: Actually, the firewall is on. @toppledwagon: you're right about port 2200. Now I get a Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-with-mic) after I continued connecting. Do I need to import the key to OS X?

Comment: You can tell it to use the key like this (assuming you saved it in ~/.ssh/key-from-VPS):  ssh -i ~/.ssh/key-from-VPS -p 2200 72.249.28.26

Comment: Hmm.. permission denied on that.

Comment: Are you sure the key you're using is the private one, and not the public? If unsure you can always generate a new one using `ssh-keygen -t dsa` on OSX and then importing the corresponding public key on the VPS. Also, as @ThoriumBR says check the permissions on .ssh (the directory) and also on authorized_keys (should be 400). And remember each public key on authorized_keys should be one long line, having line breaks is a common error if you copied/pasted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting "Permission denied", make sure that:

1 - Your key is on .ssh/authorized_keys

2 - The permissions on .ssh/authorized_keys are right. Do a `chmod -R 700 .ssh` to be sure.

Comment: I found @ThoriumBR to be part of my solution I needed: chmod -R 700 .ssh
This then allowed for the known_hosts file to be updated I am working on Mac OS X

Answer (score 1):

have you checked `/etc/hosts.deny`?  I once had the `denyhosts` daemon running by mistake and kept adding my laptop there, until I found and killed it.

Answer (score -3):

is quite a simple fix and can be completed in a few minutes via the
standard cPanel /scripts

1. Login to your server as root via SSH
2. Run: /scripts/updatenow
3. Run: /scripts/fixndc

This will fix your problems some of the time, but if it does not, do the
following steps:

1. Login to your server as root via SSH
2. Run: vi /etc/rndc.conf (or vi /etc/namedb/rndc.conf on FreeBSD)
   replace all instances of “rndc-key” with “rndckey”
3. Run: vi /etc/named.conf (or vi /etc/namedb/named.conf on FreeBSD)
   replace all instances of “rndc-key” with “rndckey”
4. Run: /scripts/fixnamed
5. Run: /scripts/fixndc
6. If you received an error in the last step, run /scripts/fixndc another
   time.
7. Restart named (on RH this is service named restart)

If you are still having issues, try checking out the cpanel forums, or
contact cpanel support for more help.

Comment: I don't see any correlation between `named` and `sshd` in this case

Comment: Sorry i copied this from some where else , its resolve my problem hopfully yours , please feel free to delete it if its not related